# Can Gitlab Auto DevOps provide an aws/dynamodb-local service without being customised?

Tags: gitlab, aws-cli

I'm using an aws/dynamodb-local Docker container for use during local testing of my Node application and I'd like to integrate it with my Gitlab CI test job.

I have made a rudimentary extension to Gitlab's Auto DevOps test job, but I'm wondering if I'm reinventing existing functionality (only worse).

My question is, can Gitlab Auto DevOps provide an aws/dynamodb-local service without being customised/extended? Am I on the right track or way off?

My `.gitlab-ci.yml` for example purposes

```
include:
  - template: Auto-DevOps.gitlab-ci.yml

test:
  stage: test
  image: node:alpine3.11
  services:
    - name: amazon/dynamodb-local:1.13.4
      alias: dynamodb-local
  variables:
    DYNAMODB_LOCAL_URL: "http://dynamodb-local:8000"
  script:
    - apk add --no-cache python py-pip
    - pip install awscli
    - npm install
    - npm test
```

AWS access key, secret access key, region variables are configured in Gitlab settings.

*Edit: I should say, I'm only asking if Gitlab is able to provide this service automatically because it seems to be able to auto detect other project requirements.*